# matrix equation equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be real symmetric and square matrices. Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a positive semi-definite matrix and $\mathbf{X}$ any matrix.  Let $\mathbf{ACA}=\mathbf{X}$ and $\lambda^2\mathbf{BCB}=\mathbf{X}$. The question is what is the relation between $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ and if and when it can be other than $\mathbf{B}=\lambda^{-1}\mathbf{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to the second part of your question is: Always, as $B = - \lambda^{-1} A$ is also always a solution. I am assuming that $\lambda$ is real and non-zero.

However, I suspect that is not what you wanted to hear. It is however difficult to say something more concrete without further conditions. For example, for any orthogonal matrix $O$ that commutes with both $C$ and $X$, $B = \pm\lambda^{-1} O A O^T$ are two possible solutions.

Comment: Actually I don't have a preference to what I want to hear. What I am looking for is wether $B=EA$ is possible where E is some full-rank matrix, except a scaled identity matrix.

Comment: As I said, it depends. Do you know anything else about the matrices $A,C,X$?

Comment: I realise now that X is symmetric as well but I see that this follows from the properties of A and C. i.e. $A^TC^TA^T=ACA$. Other than that I dont know anything else. However, it will suffice to show that the columns(rows) of B cannot(or can) be in the same direction as the columns of A. Your solution of $B=\pm \lambda^{-1}OAO^T$ implies that $B$ is in the same direction as $A$ since orthogonal matrices preserve angles? Is that right?

Comment: In fact, X is moreover necessarily non-negative as it is the square of $A C^{1/2}$ with $C^{1/2}$ being the unique positive semi-definite square root of $C$. I fear I don't understand what you mean by "in the same direction".

Comment: My formalism is probably inadequate. What i mean is that the columns of B are not scaled versions of the columns of A. (the vectors do not point to the same direction)

Comment: Ok, then surely they can be "in the same direction" but, depending on what $C$ and $X$ are, they don't necessarily have to be.